Merging multiple JSON data blocks into a single entity
I'm using an API (from SyncroMSP) that returns paginated JSON data. I can obtain the number of pages, and I can obtain the data with a tool such as curl. Each chunk is valid JSON but it only contains a subset of the total data that I need.
Using jq or otherwise how can I merge the tickets[] elements of these paginated data chunks back into a single JSON document?
Here are three example chunks. The tickets[] arrays are heavily edited for this question and in reality contain up to 25 entries, and each ticket entry contains many more elements including at least a couple of arrays.
JSON example block 1 (part_1.json)
{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "number": 4445,
      "subject": "Your mailbox is almost full"
    },
    {
      "number": 4444,
      "subject": "Cannot VPN"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
      "total_pages": 3,
      "page": 1
  }
}

JSON example block 2 (part_2.json)
{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "number": 4395,
      "subject": "Trados Studio issue"
    },
    {
      "number": 4394,
      "subject": "Daily Backup Report(No Errors)"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
      "total_pages": 3,
      "page": 2
  }
}

JSON example block 3 (part_3.json)
{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "number": 4341,
      "subject": "Daily Backup Report(No Errors)"
    },
    {
      "number": 4340,
      "subject": "Windows Updates on VMs"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
      "total_pages": 3,
      "page": 3
  }
}

In this case the expected result would be something like this:
{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "number": 4445,
      "subject": "Your mailbox is almost full"
    },
    {
      "number": 4444,
      "subject": "Cannot VPN"
    },
    {
      "number": 4395,
      "subject": "Trados Studio issue"
    },
    {
      "number": 4394,
      "subject": "Daily Backup Report(No Errors)"
    },
    {
      "number": 4341,
      "subject": "Daily Backup Report(No Errors)"
    },
    {
      "number": 4340,
      "subject": "Windows Updates on VMs"
    }
  ]
}

The output could include the meta hash too, as I'd just ignore it, and it wouldn't matter which meta.page value was carried forward.
You can assume that tickets[].number is unique and that you do not need to preserve any ordering at that tickets[] level. There's enough complexity in the real data that I don't want to have to declare the full JSON structure in any resulting code.
This is my current attempt, but I'm not particularly strong with jq. Is there a better way - for example, not calling jq twice, or being able to generalise the code so that I don't need to specify the name of the top level array (tickets)?
cat part_{1,2,3}.json | jq '.tickets[]' | jq -n '{ tickets:[ inputs ] }'


Would something like jq 'reduce inputs as $d (.; . * $d)' *.json work?

@MarcusMüller that seems to give me the same as part_3.json (the last input file)

You can use map | add to merge all of the tickets into a single array:
jq -s '{tickets: map(.tickets) | add}' part_{1..3}.json

Or with parameterisation of tickets,
key=$(jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.value | type == "array") | .key' part_1.json)
jq -s --arg key "$key" '{ ($key): map(.[$key]) | add }' part_{1..3}.json

Or with one jq invocation:
jq -s '
  (
    first | to_entries[] | select(.value|type == "array") | .key
  ) as $key |
  {
    ($key): map(.[$key]) | add
  }' part_{1..3}.json


Wow. So simple!

@ChrisDavies: Yeah I can't figure out how to not have to mention the top level array though but I'm sure Kusalananda will be here shortly with that solution heh.

From this  I can write some generalised code. But I'd love to see how to avoid mentioning tickets[]

@ChrisDavies To make the expression completely generic would probably be possible, but the price you would pay for that is a much longer and complicated expression to maintain.

@Kusalananda thank you. At that point I'll go with this solution and generalise outside jq in my shell code

@ChrisDavies Jesse's code is trivially parametrizable as jq -s --arg key tickets '{ ($key): map(.[$key]) | add }' part_[123].json.

@ChrisDavies Thats what I thought you meant by writing generalized code but it still requires you know that the array is called tickets.  You could do something like cat part1.json | jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.value | type == "array") | .key' to get it but then it starts getting really verbose, and also might not work if your json has multiple arrays

I'll know the array's called tickets because I'll be processing tickets rather than (say) assets or customers. And the structure & contents will be different for each anyway. But the process for unpaginating the data will be the same regardless
